# Display with twice the same refresh rate, one works, the other does not

Tags: display, vga-adapter

My external display has two refresh rate settings, but both have the same 60 Hz value:

[image]

If I select the topmost, the screen image is too wide for the screen. If I select the bottom value, all works well.
Unfortunately on connecting the display it defaults to the topmost 60 Hz value, which means I need to manually set the refresh rate on each connect.

Why are there two (psuedo) identical refresh rates?
How can I default to the correct one?

I'm on a Macbook Pro 5,3 with OSX 10.11.6. I connect to the display via the mini-displayport to VGA adapter.